# Run time error 424. VBA if worksheet is called "In Progress" then execute code Else Msg Box

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code and what it does is it allows a user to open a dialog box then select an excel file. This selected excel file then gets formatted, it then puts a filter on the 8th column it then creates new excel sheets copies and pastes the information to these sheets and names the new sheet based on the data in the 8th column.

So I end up with an excel workbook like the one you see in Pic 1

As you can see in PIC 1 I have the original sheet "Searchcaseresults" and the sheets "In Progress" and "Complete"

What I am trying to achieve is code that goes if in this workbook there is a sheet called "In Progress" then execute code on that sheet if there is not a sheet called "in Progress then Msg Box "no In progress sheet found" or do nothing and if there is a sheet in this workbook called "Complete" then execute code and if there is no sheet called Complete in this workbook then Msg Box "no complete sheet found" or do nothing.

At the moment I have not entered the Complete code because I getting **Run time error 424** on line `If Worksheet.Name = "In Progress" Then` and I would like to solve this first.

The area of code that is giving me trouble is here

```
 ''''Trouble code
    Dim wb As Workbook

    With wb

    If Worksheet.Name = "In Progress" Then
    Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits Columns
    Range("E1").Value = "# days open" '<--|Enters Value
    Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

    Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("In Progress")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row '<--|Looks for the last non empty cell in C

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("E" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("D" & i).Value, Date) '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract todays date from C and populate in D
    Next i
    End With
    Else
    MsgBox "In Progress Sheet not Found"

    End If

    End With
```

and my code in its entirety is below PIC 1

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

PIC 1

[image]

TOTAL CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName


Call Sample     '<--|Calls the sample Code and executes

End If


End Sub

Public Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String


    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)


    With ws

    Rows("1:5").Delete

    End With

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:AH50").Find(What:="Issue No", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    '~~> Cut the entire column
    aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

    '~~> Insert the column here
    Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Else
    MsgBox "Country Not Found"

    End If
    End With

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:AH50").Find(What:="NPI Number", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    '~~> Cut the entire column
    aCell.EntireColumn.Cut

    '~~> Insert the column here
    Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    Else
    MsgBox "Country Not Found"

    End If
    End With

    With ws

    Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("A1").Value = "Market"
    Cells(1, 2).Copy
    Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns.AutoFit
    Range("O:AH").EntireColumn.Delete
    Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25

    End With

        With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Formula = "=If(B2<>"""",""Enter Your Country Here"","""")"
        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value
        .Range("A2:A" & lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    End With

    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With ws '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(8).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 7th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 8, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (7th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).EntireColumn.Delete '<--| clear helper column (header included)


    ''''Trouble code
    Dim wb As Workbook

    With wb

    If Worksheet.Name = "In Progress" Then
    Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits Columns
    Range("E1").Value = "# days open" '<--|Enters Value
    Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

    Dim LastRow  As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("In Progress")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row '<--|Looks for the last non empty cell in C

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("E" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("D" & i).Value, Date) '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract todays date from C and populate in D
    Next i
    End With
    Else
    MsgBox "In Progress Sheet not Found"

    End If

    End With

   End Sub
```

I have simplified the code but I am still getting an error the error I am now getting is **run-time error 91**

The **run-time error 91** is happening on line `If worksheet.name = "In Progress" Then`

The code I am trying to get to work is below

```
Public Sub Msg_Box()

Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim worksheet As worksheet


    With wb
    If worksheet.name = "In Progress" Then
    MsgBox "found"
    Else
    MsgBox "not found"


    End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `For...Loop` code in your `With wb...End With` code and iterate over all the sheets.

Comment: Hi ManishChristian: Thank you for taking the time to respond I have tried a loop but it also failed I used this as an example http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44050-vba-ignore-if-sheet-name-is-equal-to/ but I was unlucky and could not bring in the Complete sheet

Comment: Can you update your question with updated code that you have tried from this link?

Comment: Hi Manish: I have simplified the code even further but still I am getting errors. I have reduced the code to Msg Boxes but still the errors are happening. Please see the simply code at the bottom of my original question. Again thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i think was happening is that I was not activating the the sheet name "In Progress"

The code that finally worked for me is below. Again I would to thank all those who assisted, and I hope this helps another Excel enthusiast with a solution

```
'''''Trouble code
    Dim wb As Workbook
''Dim ws As Worksheet <-- this was dotted out as it is declared earlier in the code

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
If ws.Name = "In Progress" Then
    Worksheets("In Progress").Activate ''<-- this what I believe need to happen activate the sheet
    Columns.AutoFit '<--|Auto fits Columns
    Range("E1").Value = "# days open" '<--|Enters Value
    Rows("2:2500").RowHeight = 25 '<--|Adjusts Row Height

    With Worksheets("In Progress")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row '<--|Looks for the last non empty cell in C

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        .Range("E" & i).Value = DateDiff("d", .Range("D" & i).Value, Date) '<--|As long as C is not blank it will subtract todays date from C and populate in D
    Next i
End With
    Columns(5).NumberFormat = "0"
    Range("P:P").EntireColumn.Delete
    End If


Next
```

Comment: Glad that you fixed it yourself. You can always [**accept**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer.

Comment: Manish Thank you for the kind response. Yes it is very satisfying to solve your own issue. Thank you again for the support it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function SheetExists(ByVal SheetName as String, ByRef InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean   
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print InWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Name
    If Err.Number = 0 Then SheetExists = True Else SheetExists = False
End Function
```

Use this function to test if the workbook opened has a sheet named "In Progress". For example:

```
If SheetExists("In Progress", wb) Then
    'Some code to execute
Else
    MsgBox "No In Progress sheet found"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Excel Developers: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I am curious how would the code you have supplied me work. I have not used a lot of functions in the past.

Comment: FWIW - `If Err.Number = 0 Then SheetExists = True Else SheetExists = False` can be simplified to `SheetExists = Err.Number = 0`